# Azure Pipeline (YAML) deploys an empty solution to my FunctionApp

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm building a CI-CD azure pipeline with YAML to deploy an azure function app.
Everything works fine, I can even set some properties for the function app, but my function app remains empty.

I downloaded the zip artifact and it looks just fine.

```
trigger:
- master
variables:
  variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects: '**/TestFunction.csproj'
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job:
    pool:
      vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
      continueOnError: false
    steps:    
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Restore'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        vstsFeed: '/0856b234-f3a6-4052-b5a6-ed9f6ec9c635'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Publish Build'
      inputs:
        command: publish
        arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
        projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
        publishWebProjects: false
        modifyOutputPath: true
        zipAfterPublish: false
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: "Archive Files"
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'    
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
    # track deployments on the environment
  - deployment:
    pool:
      vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
    # creates an environment if it doesn’t exist
    environment: 'dev'
    strategy:
      # default deployment strategy
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
            displayName: 'Download Artifacts'
            inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              downloadType: 'specific'
              downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'        
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy: ngproductionfetcherfuncref'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Agder Energi Sandbox (1aa9cf92-9d42-49a6-8d31-876ac2dff562)'
              appType: functionApp
              appName: myFunctionApp
              package: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/**/*.zip'
              appSettings: '-name0 value0 -name1 value1'
```

The pipeline is all green:

Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'myFunctionApp'
Updating App Service Application settings. Data: {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"1"} {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP":{"value":""}}
Updated App Service Application settings and Kudu Application settings.
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
Updating App Service Application settings. Data: {"name0":"value0","name1":"value1"} undefined
Updated App Service Application settings and Kudu Application settings.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add a question to your post?

Comment: well, it's not a question but a problem that I'm facing: no changes in my function app are deployed

Comment: probably artifacts are empty?

Comment: I downloaded the artifacts and they are not empty

Comment: I thing this question sould belong on [DevOps SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Can you share what the zip that you're deploying looks like? Just a screenshot of the root should help...

Comment: Any update on this? I'm seeing a similar issue.